# OneSignal Push-notifications Windowsphone

Tags: windows, cordova, push-notification, onesignal

I created an cordova app for Android and IOS with OneSignal push notifications in it. This is all working fine, but now I want to launch this app also on the Windows platform, but the problem is that we can't find a way to get OneSignal working. When starting the app, it sets the user into OneSignal, we can fetch the playerId and we can even add tags and fetch those. What we can't do is toggle the subscribed status and send notifications.

I hope someone is reckonizes this problem and can help me.

Best regards,
Richard

```
        // Enable to debug issues.
    window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 6, visualLevel: 0});

    var notificationOpenedCallback = function (jsonData) {
        console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    };

    window.plugins.OneSignal.init("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                   { googleProjectNumber: "xxxxxxxxxxxx" },
                                   notificationOpenedCallback);

    window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function (ids) {
        console.log('getIds: ' + JSON.stringify(ids));
    });

    window.plugins.OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
```

Comment: Share your relevant code so that other users can check.

Comment: I made a test project with the same code base I use for the real project.

Comment: Everything in your code looks correct. The issue is more likely related to your project setup. Double check the all the steps in [6. Windows Phone 8.1](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/phonegap-sdk-installation#6-windows-phone-81-wp81-click-to-expand). Lastly the OneSignal Cordova plugin only works with Windows Phone 8.1.